# How does the ADS-B signal transmission randomization work?

Tags: faa-regulations, ads-b

As the FAA mentions, the ADS-B messages like Identification, Position and Velocity are transmitted randomly uniquely between $ 04 \pm 02 $ sec.

How does the transmitter define that randomization? Is it standard or fixed or else who decides that?

Comment: Presumably it uses a form of a [Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation), like any other computer would use to generate random numbers. I'm also not sure that "standard/fixed randomization" is a concept that exists.

Comment: The random delay is introduced by a function called General Formatter / Manager, it is uniform and its unit of time must be less than 15 ms. Non cryptographic uniform random sequences are usually obtained using [Linear-feedback shift registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) but I don't know what is used for ADS-B Out..

Answer (score 3):

The standard DO-260B dictates that ADS-B devices must generate [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) random numbers. They do that by using a [PNRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) algorithm.

Note sure where the number $ 04 \pm 02 $ comes from, indeed the broadcast randomization specifications are the following ([source§7.3.2](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Documents/edocs/Mode%20S%20DAPs%20Implementation%20and%20Operations%20Guidance%20Document%20Ed%205.pdf)):

| Message | Condition | Interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Airborne position | - | $ 0.5 \pm 0.1 $ sec |
| Airborne velocity | - | $ 0.5 \pm 0.1 $ sec |
| Surface position | Moving | $ 0.5 \pm 0.1 $ sec |
| Surface position | Stationary on ground | $ 5 \pm 0.2 $ sec |
| Aircraft idententification | Moving or Airbone | $ 5 \pm 0.2 $ sec |
| Aircraft idententification | Stationary on ground | $ 10 \pm 0.2 $ sec |
| TSS | Airbone and valid state | $ 1.25 \pm 0.05 $ sec |
| Aircraft Operational Status | Various conditions | Complex (see source) |